# In-Place Editing in DataTable with X-Editable using PHP Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable, x-editable

I use DataTable to display data, but now I need to change the data in the table.

[image] I found a tutorial on youtube that uses the X-Editable library for that purpose. I adjusted the functionality and everything was fine until I got to the data update part.
In that tutorial, he uses 2 parameters that he uses when executing the query, which he places in the post (name and id), but what I need is the third parameter for the year, and I have never been able to figure out how to place the value for the year in the post and send it to the update .php. I hope I explained well. Below is the code, I hope someone has an idea how to do this. Thanks in advance

This is how I get the data and display it in a table

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var dataTable = $('#sample_data').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "order":[],
            "pageLength": 100,
    "ajax":{
        url:"fetch_mesec.php",
        type:"POST",
    },
    createdRow:function(row, data, rowIndex)
    {
        $.each($('td', row), function(colIndex){
                            if(colIndex == 5)
            {
                $(this).attr('data-name', 'januar');
                $(this).attr('class', 'januar');
                $(this).attr('data-type', 'number');
                $(this).attr('data-pk', data[3]);
                $(this).attr('data-year', data[4]);

            }
                            if(colIndex == 6)
            {
                $(this).attr('data-name', 'februar');
                $(this).attr('class', 'februar');
                $(this).attr('data-type', 'number');
                $(this).attr('data-pk', data[3]);
                $(this).attr('data-year', data[4]);

            }
                            if(colIndex == 7)
            {
                $(this).attr('data-name', 'mart');
                $(this).attr('class', 'mart');
                $(this).attr('data-type', 'number');
                $(this).attr('data-pk', data[3]);
                $(this).attr('data-year', data[4]);

            }
           // ...
        // I removed the repetitive code, so there is less code
        });
    }
});
```

This code works fine, the problem now starts when I want to do a single row upgrade

```
$('#sample_data').editable({
    container:'body',
    selector:'td.januar',
    url:"update.php",
    title:'Januar',
    validate:function(value){
        if($.trim(value) == '')
        {
            return 'Obavezno polje';
        }
    }
       
});
```

The query should look like this

```
include_once("private/initialize.php");
$query = "UPDATE mesec SET ".$_POST["name"]." = '".$_POST["value"]."' 
WHERE customer_no = '".$_POST["pk"]." AND godina = '".$_POST["year"]."'";
$dbc->query($query);
```

It is clear to me that it takes the value for name from
$(this).attr('data-name', 'januar'); and places it in $_POST["name"].
The same goes for the customer code, take the value from $(this).attr('data-pk', data[3]); and put it in $_POST["pk"]. But when I tried to use the same logic and take the values for the year in the
$(this).attr('data-order', data[4]); I am getting this message

> Warning: Undefined array key "year"

it is clear to me why i get that error because the year value is not placed in the post what I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: You are open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even data from the database, [you are still at risk of corrupting your data](https://bobby-tables.com/). If this is a school project. Best time to learn. How to do things right.